# System.Data.SqlClient Package is installed but isnt recognized as a Using statement in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: sql, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, using

Like the title says, I've installed both the System and Microsoft `.Data.SqlClient` SQL packages, and my code only recognizes the Microsoft one, but it doesn't recognize the `using System.Data.SqlClient;` statement. I've done this process before successfully in a console app, but in the XamForms app it doesn't work. As a result, I cannot use the `SqlConnection` or `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataReader` objects which make it a tad bit difficult to make a SQL database app if ya know what I mean.

I want to put my "login" to my SQL server in a separate file so that I can change them easily should I decide to launch this app publicly. My best guess is that I have to do this in a specific part of the XamForms app, but I don't know where if there is a specific spot. For the time being however, I would just like to get the `.Data.SqlClient` working regardless of where I put it.

Comment: System.Data.Sqlclient has dependencies on libraries that do not exist in iOS/Android.  And even if they did, it is a really, really, really bad idea to have direct access from a mobile app to your SQL server.  This is how SQL servers get hacked and companies lose their users data and then get sued out of existence.

Comment: You could use sqlite instead. Install `sqlite-net-pcl` from NuGet. And for more details, please check teh MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: @Jason - Could you write your comment as an answer so I can accept it? That makes sense, so I'm going to explore other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.Sqlclient` has dependencies on libraries that do not exist in iOS/Android. And even if they did, it is a really, really, really bad idea to have direct access from a mobile app to your SQL server. This is how SQL servers get hacked and companies lose their users data and then get sued out of existence.